# Error message about the plot in regression model

Tags: r, plot

I have an R programm for a regression that somehow gives me an error message that I do not understand. The regression model takes as input heat input heat data (Q_htg) and the corresponding temperature data (T_amb) and then builds a linear regression for those two variables. Afterwards I want to use the trained regression model to predict some outputs. Here is the code:

```
dalinearPowerScaling2.function <-
  function(Dataset,
           numberOfDaysForAggregation,
           normOutsideTemperature) {
    heatingPower <- Dataset$Q_htg
    outSideTemperature <- Dataset$T_amb
    aggregationLevel <- numberOfDaysForAggregation * 1440
    index <- 0
    meanValuesOutsideTemperature <-
      vector(, length(outSideTemperature) / aggregationLevel)
    for (i in seq(1, length(outSideTemperature), aggregationLevel)) {
      sum <- 0
      for (j in seq(i, i + aggregationLevel - 1, 1)) {
        sum <- sum + outSideTemperature[j]
      }
      index <- index + 1
      meanValuesOutsideTemperature[index] <- sum / aggregationLevel
    }
    index <- 0
    meanValuesHeatingDemand <-
      vector(, length(heatingPower) / aggregationLevel)
    for (i in seq(1, length(heatingPower), aggregationLevel)) {
      sum <- 0
      for (j in seq(i, i + aggregationLevel - 1, 1)) {
        sum <- sum + heatingPower[j]
      }
      index <- index + 1
      meanValuesHeatingDemand[index] <- sum / aggregationLevel
    }

    linearModel <-
      lm(meanValuesHeatingDemand ~ meanValuesOutsideTemperature)
    abline(linearModel, col = "red")

    pred <- predict(linearModel, data.frame(meanValuesOutsideTemperature = c(normOutsideTemperature)))
    List<-list(meanValuesHeatingDemand, meanValuesOutsideTemperature)
    List2 <- vector("list", length(heatingPower)/aggregationLevel)
    for (i in seq(1, length(meanValuesHeatingDemand),1)){
    List2 [[i]]<-c(meanValuesHeatingDemand[i], meanValuesOutsideTemperature[i])
      }

    List3<-List2[order(sapply(List2, function(x) x[1], simplify=TRUE), decreasing=FALSE)]

    firstTemperatureWithHeatingDemand<-0
    firstHeatingDemand<-0
    for (i in seq(1, length(List3), 1)) {
    if(List3[[i]][1]>0) {
      firstTemperatureWithHeatingDemand<-List3[[i]][2]
      firstHeatingDemand<-List3[[i]][1]
      break}
    }
    regression2ValuesX <- vector(, 5)
    regression2ValuesY <- vector(, 5)
    regression2ValuesX [1] <- firstTemperatureWithHeatingDemand
    regression2ValuesY [1] <-firstHeatingDemand
    List3<-List2[order(sapply(List2, function(x) x[1], simplify=TRUE), decreasing=TRUE)]
    for (i in seq(1, length(regression2ValuesX) - 1, 1)) {
      regression2ValuesX[i + 1]<-List3[[i]][2]
      regression2ValuesY[i + 1]<-List3[[i]][1]
      }

    plot(regression2ValuesX, regression2ValuesY)
    linearModel2 <-
      lm(regression2ValuesY ~ regression2ValuesX)
    abline(linearModel2, col = "blue")
    pred <- predict(linearModel2, data.frame(regression2ValuesX = c(normOutsideTemperature)))
    paste("Predicted heating demand:", round(pred))
  }
```

When I run with the command

```
linearPowerScaling2.function(data_heat_test, 1, -12)
```

I get the error message:

```
 Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet 
3.
int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) 
2.
abline(linearModel, col = "red") at LinearPowerScaling2_Function.R#33
1.
linearPowerScaling2.function(data_heat_test, 1, -12)
```

The data itself should be okay. Can anyone tell me, what the problem is?

Comment: Try `plot(meanValuesHeatingDemand ~ meanValuesOutsideTemperature)` just before the `abline` call to open the graphics device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reproducible **minimal** example it's hard to test if this solves it, but the error message tells you that you are calling abline() **before** calling plot().

That's exactly what happens on line 33...

Hope this helps.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer dario. Really strange for me is that I cut the line 33 and pasted it somewhere below but I still get the same error message even with the same faulty line 33 altough there is no code in line 33. Do I have to update somehow the function file (other than saving it)?

Comment: Yes, you have to re-run the function definition. Best practice is to restart the R environment from time to time (or manually empty the enviornment).

Comment: Thanks dario for your comment. What do you mean by "re-run the function definition"? I work with the console in R studio and when I again try to use the functio n with the command "linearPowerScaling2.function(data_heat_test, 1, -12)" I get the same error message

Comment: By "re-run" the function definition I mean executing the code of the function definition, either by sourcing the script, copy/pasting the code to the console or (at least in Ubuntu RStudio) selecting the code and pressing CTRL+ENTER.

If you run the name of a function (**without** parentheses, i.e. *mean*) in the console, R tells you what definition it is currently using.

Comment: Thanks dario for your comment. Unfortunately I don't understand what to do. I tried in the console: "re-run(linearPowerScaling2)" but I get an error message

Comment: Thanks dario for your edited comment: I marked the whole function and clicked on a button called "Run" in RStudio. Then the whole function was passed to the console.When I then press "Enter" to execute it, nothing happens except that I go one line down in the Console. When I try to execute the function again with the parameters ""linearPowerScaling2.function(data_heat_test, 1, -12)"" I get the same error message with the same faulty line 33 that does not contain any code now

Comment: This does not sound right ;)

1. Re-start your R Session and execute the function definition again.
2. Check the output of running 'linearPowerScaling2.function'.
3. Did you name the function correctly? Do you use the correct name when calling the function? (For example, in your code above the function is called **da**linearPowerScaling2.function in the definition but later you call linearPowerScaling2.function (without **da**)!

If you have more problems please supply a **minimal** example!!

Comment: Thanks dario for your answer. I think the problem is that I do not know how to run the function. If I rename the function to llinearPowerScaling3.function and try to run it from the console, I get the error message "Error: could not find function "linearPowerScaling3.function"" altough the function exists (or at least the function in the separate file has this name; however the file itself has the name "LinearPowerScaling2_Function.R"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207016/discussion-between-dario-and-peterbe).